# USB device detection unreliable

Tags: devices, alsa, usb-device

I am running an Arch Linux and I have some issue with USB audio device detection on the running system.

The detection works fine most of the time and is totally reliable on reboot, but especially when I forgot to plugin my headset before joining a BBB session my system will not correctly detect the audio device.
I also noticed that my system is similarly unreliable in detecting USB volumes.
My system is set up to auto-mount. Sometimes they show up, sometimes they don't.

Until now, I simply rebooted and avoided to face the problem by simply rebooting (as this seems a 100% reliable), but I do wonder

- why this is happening,
- how to trouble-shoot this and
- how to fix this

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is, but it would probably help to provide more details of your hardware.

Comment: I'll provide them if the information is required as I have no reason at the moment to suspect a hardware problem ;)

Comment: Look for error messages in your log - for example, try `dmesg | grep -i audio`